# BIP Report Layout - Chart Values rounding up and showing as K (thousands)

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, bi-publisher, oraclereports, oracle-analytics, oracle-analytics-cloud

I am using Oracle PLM Cloud Version 24A (11.12.24.01.0) And I am creating a data model with FSCM Database source and then I am creating report template on top of it.

I'm currently utilizing Oracle BIP Report Layout, and within my charts, I'm displaying item counts. However, I'm encountering an issue where the counts are being shown in thousands and are also being rounded up. My objective is to display the numbers as they are, without any scaling.

Could you please assist me in resolving this matter? Please look at screenshot for reference. [SCREENSHOT ATTACHED:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7KvA.png)

Thank you.

Found no formatting regarding this in the settings.